# Using BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE on Windows with MinGW64

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw-w64, boost-stacktrace

I am building a Qt application using Windows and MinGW64. I need to use Boost Stacktrace to generate stack traces like the Linux build of the application already does.

The corresponding switch `BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE` (as described in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html) is set and everything works fine on Linux.

However on Windows the `libbacktrace` library is missing. The above boost page contains two links to the sources of `libbacktrace` but I couldn't find a prebuilt binary for Windows/MinGW nor could I find any build instructions or usage documentation for my environment.

How can I use `BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE` with Windows/MinGW64?

Comment: Windows already has stack trace capability with mini dumps and [stack walk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/).

Comment: [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump). That's some real useful information for diagnostics. Unlike stack traces, that require an application to publish its private symbol database, and doesn't capture any useful state. I'm not sure why this surprises so many developers, but Windows is **far** better a development platform than anything out there.

Comment: Since this is a cross-plattform application I would like the Linux and Windows builds to behave essentially the same. So I would like to stick with boost and libbacktrace if possible.

Comment: If you don't want to write different code for either target platform, then simply don't write any code for Windows. Have the installer set up Windows Error Reporting and get all your crash dumps for free. On Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem (and some more issues) by switching to MSYS2 UCRT. MSYS2 provides a precompiled libbacktrace package.